# width of div is not increasing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, width

Here is my code:

```
<script>
var change = function(){
    alert("sam");
    for(var i; i >=200; i++){
         var z = String(i);
        var x=  document.getElementById("div1");
       x.style.width = z;   
    } 

};
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    #div1{
        width:100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color:#ccc;
    }
</style>
<div id="div1"></div>
<button onclick="change();"> click</button>
```

what actually this code does, it will increase the width. like in jquery we increase the width, as its width is sliding,.. i am trying to do like this width javascript.

and when i tested this out in google chrome, it dosen't showed any mistake or error, but the width of that div dosen't change and it should be noted that, it alerted `sam`!

please tell me my mistake...Thanks!

Comment: your code doesn't make any sense, because already that div's width is 100px, again you are setting its width as 100px through a for loop..! what is your objective anyway.?

Comment: Are you trying to perform animation?

Comment: yes... i want to animate

Comment: How about using [animate()](https://api.jquery.com/animate/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is going to be a little more complex:

```
var change = function() {

    var div = document.getElementById("div1"),
        startWidth = div.offsetWidth;

    for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        (function(i) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                div.style.width = startWidth + i + 'px';
            }, i * 10)
        })(i) // wrap setTimeout in a closure
    }
};
```

A couple notes.

1). You need to calculate an initial width. You can use `offsetWidth` property for that.

2). Make sure you don't reselect `div` element in the loop.

3). You need a closure and `setTimeout` for sliding effect. Closure is used to bind a setTimeout with a snapshot (current in a loop) value of the `i` variable.

4). In the loop `i >= 200` should be `i <= 200`.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/z58p6/1/

Answer (score 2):

From your question, I guess you want to perform smooth transition by increasing width.

If you can use CSS3, try the following code. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4Abt9/2/)

```
<script>
var change = function(){
    alert("sam");
    var x=  document.getElementById("div1");
    x.style.width = "500px";
};
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    #div1{
        width:100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color:#ccc;
        -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
        -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
        -o-transition: all .5s ease;
        transition: all .5s ease;
    }
</style>
<div id="div1"></div>
<button onclick="change();"> click</button>
```

Comment: and what is the meaning of `all` and `ease` in this css code?

Comment: and another more interesting thing to note is that how did you communicate between css and javascript

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few errors.

```
<script>
var change = function(){
alert("sam");
for(var i=0; i <=200; i++){
     var z = i;


} 
        var x = document.getElementById("div1");
       x.style.width = z+'px'; 

};
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#div1{
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:#ccc;
}
</style>
<div id="div1"></div>
<button onclick="change();"> click</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6WsCR/

BTW you do not need the loop and could just do this:

```
<script>
 var change = function(z){
        var x = document.getElementById("div1").style.width = z+'px';
};
</script>
    <button onclick="change(500);"> click</button>
```

EDIT: what you want is this

```
<script>
var changeAnimate = function(){
$('#div1').animate({
width: '200px',
  }, 5000, function() {
  });
    }
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#div1{
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:#ccc;
}
</style>
<div id="div1"></div>
<button onclick="changeAnimate();"> click</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pfP37/

Comment: You are better off using this then. https://api.jquery.com/animate/  if using jquery is an option that is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function resizeDiv(id,ud) {
       var Div=document.getElementById(id);
       var width=parseInt(Div.style.width)+ud;
       if (width>=1){
          Div.style.width = width + "em"; 
       }
    }
  </script>
  <div id="div_test" style="height: 1em; width: 1em; border:1px solid;">You div</div>
  <input type="button" value="increase" onclick="resizeDiv('div_test', 1);">
  <p></p> 
  <input type="button" value="decrease" onclick="resizeDiv('div_test', -1);">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "px" as follows

*var z = String(i)+"px";*

```
var change = function(){
    alert("sam");
    for(var i; i >=200; i++){
        var z = String(i);
        var x=  document.getElementById("div1");
        x.style.width = z + "px";   
    } 

};
```